# Passing Object to smart contract's payable function

Tags: solidity, remix

I'm developing a contract where I should be able to pay multiple user's addresses.
I'm using TRON blockchain. I can use the TRONIDE developer API to send funds. But they recently shutdown their API for some reason so I think the better option would be to use the smart contract itself.

I can populate the address and the equivalent amount to transfer to each address and then pay the total amount from my DAPP.

```
{
'address1' : 10000,
'address2' : 20000,
'address3' : 50000
}
```

This would be my object.

So I'll create a DAPP to send 80000 in total and this object to my contract and my contract will distribute the funds accordingly.

I tried the below code but I keep getting errors (Mentioned below) Please help.

```
function performBonusCredit(string[][] _toPayArgs) external payable {
        //Perform send function here
    }
```

```
TypeError: Data location must be "calldata" for parameter in external function, but none was given.
function performBonusCredit(string toPayArgs) external payable {
                            ^--------------^
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add `calldata` to the parameter. So the signature should be:

```
function performBonusCredit(string[][] calldata _toPayArgs) external payable {
```

You can read more about these data location markers here: https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.0/types.html#data-location

Comment: Hi, I solved the issue by using `uint256[] memory topayargs` array declaration. 
Now I have an issue in calling this function from DAPP. When I send the array through the calling function, the values shows as 'NaN'.